# iterate list of dictionary and append python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a List of dictionaries (a) and i'm trying to iterate through the dictionaries search for a specific value and if the dictionary has that value add that dictionary to a new collection of dictionaries. So far i have

```
newList = {}

a = [{"one": "green", "two" : "blue", "three" : "red"},
     {"two": "blue", "four" : "green", "five" : "yellow"},
     {"two": "blue", "six": "white", "seven" : "black"}]

for index in range(len(a)):
 if a[index][?] = ["blue"]:
   newList.append(a[index])
```

Comment: it's confusing to call a `dict` type `newList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying, but I modified your example as little as possible to achieve your goal:

```
ewList = []
a = [{"one": "green", "two": "blue", "three": "red"},
     {"two": "blue", "four" : "green", "five" : "yellow"},
     {"two": "yellow", "six": "white", "seven" : "black"}]

for d in a:
    if "yellow" in d.values():
        ewList.append(d)

print ewList
```

Output:

```
[{'four': 'green', 'five': 'yellow', 'two': 'blue'}, {'seven': 'black', 'six': 'white', 'two': 'yellow'}]
```

Comment: This tests if the key is 'blues', is that the required behaviour? (I guess you meant if 'blue' in d:)

Answer (score 5):

The data structure you have is not quite convenient for this use case/query. If you cannot change the data structure, here is a naive solution:

```
newList = [d for d in a if "blue" in d.values()]
```

Note that `if "blue" in d.values()` lookup is `O(n)` which is what you should ideally try to avoid when performing `in` lookups.

---

A more suitable data structure in this case would be the one that has the key and values in the inner dictionaries swapped:

```
a = [{"green": "one", "blue": "two", "red": "three"},
     {"blue": "two":, "green": "four", "yellow": "five"},
     {"blue": "two", "white": "six", "black": "seven"}]
```

In this case, you would look into the dictionaries by key which would be `O(1)`:

```
newList = [d for d in a if "blue" in d]
```